# Using concurrent threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, awt

I have a program (an AWT Frame, yes I know that Swing is better but I am restricted from using it) that has 2 moving objects. So I thought I would put each in its own thread to allow the objects to move at different speeds, etc.

One thread (`gameThread`) handles a bouncing ball, and the other (`cannonThread`) handles a cannon drawn on the screen and the projectiles fired by it. I was unsure of how to seperate the ball's speed and the projectile's speed which is why I thought 2 threads would work (by using `thread.sleep(speedofobject)`).

I don't know how to implement them and my random guess (obviously) didn't work. Nothing shows up on the screen and there are no errors generated at compile time. Previously, the ball would show up on the screen and move around as it should.

Here's a snippet from where I tried to do multiple threads. If you need more information, let me know and I'll post it.

```
public void start()
{
    if (gameThread == null)
    {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }
    if (cannonThread == null)
    {
        cannonThread = new Thread(this);
        cannonThread.start();
    }       
}

public void run()
    {
        //thread for the ball, collision detection and scorekeeping
        if (Thread.currentThread().equals(gameThread))
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            while (!kill)
            {
                if (!paused)
                {
                    target.repaint();
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(ballSpeed);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){System.err.println("Interrupted.");}
            }
            stop(); 
        }

        //thread for the cannon and projectile
        if (Thread.currentThread().equals(cannonThread))
        {
            Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
            if (!paused)
            {
                if (projectileFiring)
                {
                    cannon.repaint();
                }
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(projectileSpeed);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){System.err.println("Interrupted.");}
            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a separate thread for each object in your world is not the way to go. One way to deal with this is to have a single separate thread that is responsible for updating the "world model" (in your case, the ball and the cannon). This world model thread would run the following animation loop:

1. sleep for a short time
2. update the data representing the ball and cannon based on the current time
3. Signal that the UI needs to be updated with the current model

Note that with this approach, you will need to synchronize access to the model data, because it will be updated by the animation loop in one thread and read by the rendering code to update the UI. You don't want the data changing as you are reading it.

Comment: thats a good point, so just have an `updateBall` and an `updateCannon` instead of a thread apiece. Only thing I am cuious about is how to independently gauge speed of the projectile and the ball. I was using `thread.sleep(value)` as the speed of the ball, where a smaller `value` would make it move faster and vice versa. Is there a good way to do this without using `thread.sleep()`, or a craftier way to use that method for two objects in one thread?

Comment: @ZakParks - Maintain separate variables for the various velocities you need to track. Keep the velocities in some standard units (e.g., pixels/second). Multiply the relevant velocity by the elapsed time from the previous update to determine the displacement to apply. This way, your visual speeds will be under direct control of the velocity variables rather than varying based on the animation loop timing.